# call an API from App script and send binary data as a POST parameter

Tags: google-apps-script, http-post, urlfetch

I'm trying to use an API, the CURL command is this one :

```
curl --user "<your-client-id>:<your-client-secret>" "https://api.everypixel.com/v1/faces?url=https://labs.everypixel.com/api/static/i/estest_sample3.jpg"
```

In my use case, I'm sending images from those type of urls : https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C5603AQFLzBsLRsZBXQ/profile-displayphoto-shrink_800_800/0/1652669513751?e=1674086400&v=beta&t=-NC598zxFjG9fDOMJeqmLuYrP0e9NnCv92aup4MK2Wk

My problem is handling the image as the image url is not a jpg / png like the example in the CRUL command.

My script looks like this :

```
  var url = "https://api.everypixel.com/v1/faces";

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
      "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "user": "<your-client-id>:<your-client-secret>"
    },
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
    "followRedirects": true,
    "validateHttpsCertificates": true,
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "payload": JSON.stringify({
      "url": "https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C4D03AQEnKuhl53UqCA/profile-displayphoto-shrink_800_800/0/1563935310527?e=2147483647&v=beta&t=8x-OjnqJCg6U7jt9Zm2rRscO22pG5C5QvgSh7H9lfSI"
    })
  });

  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to convert the following curl command to Google Apps Script.

  ```
    curl --user "<your-client-id>:<your-client-secret>" "https://api.everypixel.com/v1/faces?url=https://labs.everypixel.com/api/static/i/estest_sample3.jpg"
  ```

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const url = `https://api.everypixel.com/v1/faces?url=${encodeURIComponent("https://labs.everypixel.com/api/static/i/estest_sample3.jpg")}`;
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    "headers": { "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("<your-client-id>:<your-client-secret>") },
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
  });
  const data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
}
```

- The sample curl command is the GET method.
- `url=https://labs.everypixel.com/api/static/i/estest_sample3.jpg` is the query parameter.
- `--user "<your-client-id>:<your-client-secret>"` is the basic authorization.

#### Note:

- I think that the request of this modified script is the same as the curl command. But, if an error occurs, please confirm the values of `<your-client-id>:<your-client-secret>` and the URL again.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: @Steph Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.